# Partition a line around intersections

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, intersection

I've got a bunch of lines (ideally in a single `Region`) as well as a single new line, e.g.:

```
region = RegionUnion @@ Line /@ Table[{{x, -1}, {x, 1}}, {x, 3}]
line = Line @ {{0, 0}, {4, 0}}
```

I want to find all the intersections between `region` and `line` and want to use those to partition `line` into a bunch of sub-lines that don't cross any of the intersections. That is, for the above example I want the lines:

```
Line /@ { {{0,0}, {1,0}},
          {{1,0}, {2,0}},
          {{2,0}, {3,0}},
          {{3,0}, {4,0}} }
```

I also need these lines in order (having the order reversed is fine, I just want to be able to find the first and last segment easily).

Of course I could implement this myself by solving a bunch of simple equations, but I was hoping Mathematica's myriad of built-ins allow for a simpler/more idiomatic solution (the issue with solving this based on line intersection is that I have to test for each line in `region` separately, whereas the `Region*` functions can treat the entire region as a single entity). I tried working with `RegionDifference[line, region]`, but Mathematica isn't able to express the resulting segments as new `Line` objects (presumably, because `RegionDifference` results in open sets and `Line` represents a closed set, which I'd be fine with).

Is there any decent way to solve this with a handful of built-ins based on regions, or will I have to roll my own solution solving line equations?

Answer (score 6):

You're correct in that MMA provides a simpler way to find the intersections:

```
intersections = Solve[{x, y} \[Element] region && {x, y} \[Element] line, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 2, y -> 0}, {x -> 3, y -> 0}}

Dividing up your line is then something of another problem in itself as many factor come into play: Is your line one single straight line? Does it intersect lines in your region more than once? etc etc, So the approach you take will differ depending on what constraints you have.

The following should be a fairly general solution based on parameterising the line and finding the values of the parameter where the intersects occur.

```
Parameterise[line_] := Module[{linePts, nPts},
  linePts = line[[1]];
  nPts = Length[linePts];

  Interpolation[Transpose[{Rescale@Range[nPts], linePts}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
  ]

pLine = Parameterise[line];

tab = Table[{u, pLine[u]}, {u, 0, 1, 1/100.}];

intersects = Nearest[tab[[;; , 2]] -> tab[[;; , 1]], #] & /@ intersections[[;; , ;; , 2]];

p = Partition[Join[{0}, Sort[Flatten[intersects]], {1}], 2, 1]
```

> {{0, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.75}, {0.75, 1}}

```
Show[
 DiscretizeRegion[region],
 Table[
  ParametricPlot[pLine[u], {u, p[[i, 1]], p[[i, 2]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][i]],
  {i, 1, Length@p}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

To show its versatility:

```
line = Line@Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 4}, {4}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4}]}]
```

> Line[{{2.17744, -0.0514017}, {3.69122, -0.940829}, {0.786582, -0.670897}, {1.24424, -0.326177}}]

[image]

If I could find a way to invert the pLines function I could do away with the inelegant `tab` and `Nearest` components and directly find `u` when `f[u] = {x,y}`. Any pointers?

Comment: Ah that's quite nice, thank you. I don't even need the generality you show in the last example: the region will only consist of straight lines and `line` will always be a single, straight segment to begin with. I was specifically hoping that there would be a way to avoid the parameterisation, but using `Interpolation` for that is also a good idea. :)